# Javascript - Uncaught TypeError: Object has no method

Tags: javascript

I have this method:

```
var stopwatch = function () {
    this.start = function () {
        (...)
    };

    this.stop = function() {
        (...)
    };
};
```

When I try to invoke it:

`stopwatch.start();`

I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Object (here is my function) has no method 'start'`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning functions to `this.start` and `this.stop` *when the function `stopwatch` is run* and never running that function.

It looks like you want a constructor function, with some prototypes.

```
// By convention, constructor functions have names beginning with a capital letter
function Stopwatch () {
    /* initialisation time logic */
}

Stopwatch.prototype.stop = function () { };
Stopwatch.prototype.start = function () { };

// Create an instance
var my_stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
my_stopwatch.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do `new stopwatch().start()`?

Comment: Because you can't end that stopwatch later without saving it in a variable.

Comment: So, why not assigning the instance to a variable, like other answers do? :P

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the start function as like this,

```
var obj = new stopwatch();
obj.start();
```

You can create an instance of that method and access the start function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new object first, only then you can call functions on it:

```
var stopwatch = function () {
    this.start = function () {
        console.log('test');
    };

    this.stop = function () {

    };
};

var s = new stopwatch();
s.start();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9EWGK/